# JavaScript change wmode to opaque en masse

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, wmode

I have a site with code like this:

```
<div id="layout">
<div id="regionHero" class="regionHero">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="jupiterContent" name="jupiterContent" data="http://a.dolimg.com/explore/swf/code/moduleBootstrap.swf" width="996" height="502" wmode="opaque">
        <param name="menu" value="false"/>
        <param name="scale" value="noscale"/>
        <param name="quality" value="best"/>
        <param name="salign" value="tl"/>
        <param name="base" value="."/>
        <param name="align" value="t"/>
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
        <param name="flashVars" value="divIdDataPath=heroContent&divContainerID=regionHero&companionAdDivID=companion-ad&swfID=jupiterContent&showPreRoll=false&showTakeOver=false"/>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

I'd like to change all occurrences of wmode to opaque. Is this easily done via jquery? In the object definition, wmode is set to opaque but in the params it becomes transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you can change it, but you'll need to reload the SWF in order for it take affect. The param would be a pre-pageload setting to the Flash Player.

Comment: Oh I see.. how can I force reload?

Comment: Yes, you can... by re-embedding the HTML. It's really a sloppy task with all the parsing if you're not using something like swfobject.